# Systemd with Django UWSGI in virtualenv doesn't respond to SIGTERM on service stop

Tags: systemd, django, uwsgi

I have a Django application that is running using uWSGI within a virtual environment using systemd. I used the "normal" way to set this up according to docs, but it seems that when I stop or restart the service the SIGTERM command isn't causing the application to stop.
It is running on Amazon Linux 2023 and I did not add anything in the application to make it run/stop/restart in a specific way it is a plain Django app.

I see the following error in journalctl:
 `State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.`

My service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application uwsgi service
After=network.target syslog.target

[Service]
User=nginx
Group=nginx
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /opt/env-application/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini /opt/application/uwsgi.ini'
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = application.wsgi:application
enable-threads = true
master = true
processes = 1
plugins = python3
project = /opt/application/
chdir = %(project)
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chmod-socket = 660
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket-timeout = 3600
harakiri = 3600
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
wsgi-file=/opt/application/uwsgi.py
virtualenv = /opt/env-application/
```

My wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "application.config.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```